# How to deal with the error "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input"?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an nested sterilizer:

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Link
    fields = [
        'linkname',
        'linkurl'
    ]
 
class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
links = LinkSerializer(
    many=True,
    # queryset = Link.objects.all()
)
class Meta:
    model = Work
    fields = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'links'
    ]
```

The django models look like this:

```
class Work(models.Model):
firstname = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=10, blank=True)
lastname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=30, blank=True)
 
class Link(models.Model):
links = models.ForeignKey(Work, related_name='links', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
linkname = models.CharField("linkname", max_length=100, blank=True)
linkurl = models.CharField("linkurl", max_length=100, blank=True)
```

The django rest framework outputs the following about **Links**:

> Links: Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.

I realized that I need to work towards json For nested serializers, but it doesn't work out, so I ask for help, how would you deal with this problem. Thanks in advance to the one who will help

please take another look at the screenshot attached to the question

[Json ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGUii.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564732/lists-are-not-currently-supported-in-html-input

Comment: yes, I saw it, it doesn't suit me, I need a custom sterilizer for nested data, but I had difficulties with it